# return dictionary of file names as keys and word lists with words unique to file as values

Tags: python-3.x, function, iteration, slice

I am trying to write a function to extract only words unique to each key and list them in a dictionary output like {"key1": "unique words", "key2": "unique words", ... }. I start out with a dictionary.  To test with I created a simple dictionary:

```
d = {1:["one", "two", "three"], 2:["two", "four", 
"five"], 3:["one","four", "six"]}
```

My output should be:

```
{1:"three", 
 2:"five",
 3:"six"}
```

I am thinking maybe split in to separate lists

```
def return_unique(dct):
    Klist = list(dct.keys())
    Vlist = list(dct.values())
    aList = []
    for i in range(len(Vlist)):
        for j in Vlist[i]:
             if
```

What I'm stuck on is how do I tell Python to do this: if Vlist[i][j] is not in the rest of Vlist then aList.append(Vlist[i][j]).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
def return_unique(data):
   all_values = []
   for i in data.values():  # Get all values
       all_values = all_values + i

   unique_values = set([x for x in all_values if all_values.count(x) == 1])  # Values which are not duplicated

   for key, value in data.items():  # For Python 3.x ( For Python 2.x -> data.iteritems())
      for item in value: # Comparing values of two lists
         for item1 in unique_values:
             if item == item1:
                 data[key] = item
   return data


d = {1:["one", "two", "three"], 2:["two", "four", "five"], 3:["one","four", "six"]}
print (return_unique(d))
```

result >> {1: 'three', 2: 'five', 3: 'six'}

Answer (score 1):

Since a key may  have more than one unique word associated with it, it makes sense for the values in the new dictionary to be a container type object to hold the unique words.

The [set difference](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.difference) operator returns the difference between 2 sets:

```
>>> a = set([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = set([2, 4, 6])
>>> a - b
{1, 3}
```

We can use this to get the values unique to each key. Packaging these into a simple function yields:

```
def unique_words_dict(data):
    res = {}
    values = []
    for k in data:
        for g in data:
            if g != k:
                values += data[g]
        res[k] = set(data[k]) - set(values)
        values = []
    return res

>>> d = {1:["one", "two", "three"],
         2:["two", "four", "five"], 
         3:["one","four", "six"]}

>>> unique_words_dict(d)
{1: {'three'}, 2: {'five'}, 3: {'six'}}
```

If you only had to do this once, then you might be interested in the less efficeint but more consice dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> {k: set(d[k]) - set(reduce(lambda a, b: a+b, [d[g] for g in d if g!=k], [])) for k in d}
{1: {'three'}, 2: {'five'}, 3: {'six'}}
```